# change database url firebase while domain registration

Tags: firebase

I have a question about firebase website hosting, does the URL of my database change when I got a domain URL, I mean my URL is 'myapp.firebaseapp.com' to the new domain I have 'www.***.com'?
as far as I know it isn't possible to change the database URL after deploying your project, I'm kind of stuck and I need to change it .

Comment: Why would this matter, considering that the database URL is used internally by your app and not shown to the user at any point?

Comment: that what i was looking for, i was wondering if it still shown to the client when they search for my website.

Comment: thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a custom domain to Firebase Hosting does not change the URL of the Firebase Realtime Database, nor any of the other configuration data that Firebase SDKs may depend on.

When you add a custom domain that change only applies to Firebase Hosting, not to any other Firebase products. It also is an add-only operation, the existing, default URLs keep working after you add a custom domain.

Comment: does the URL of the Firebase Realtime still shown to the client when they search for my website?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. The database URL is an internal detail of your app, similar to its source code. The average user will neither see the source code, nor the database URL. Curious users can find either of those if they want of course.